# Android Application Development: Multiple Toggle Button with Action Listener

Tags: android, togglebutton

I'm trying to create an android application with multiple toggle button.
Each ToggleButton has two state. either ON or OFF and initially all the button are set to default, being OFF.

I have to listen to the User Action and act accordingly. How do I do this with Multiple Toggle Button.

Toggle button is arranged inform of a Matrix and I want read the state to a matrix, once user clicks the Simple Button.

Please be advised that I'm a beginner to Mobile App Development.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.toggleOne:
            // In this section u can pass intent , toast[message] on button click.
            break;

        case R.id.toggleTwo:
            // do your code
            break;

        case R.id.toggleThird:
            // do your code
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

you have to implement `onClickListener` interface to override `onClick` method